# Script cannot open file which can be opened normally

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a script which finds the pitch of a waveform, however I am getting an error that it cannot open a wav file, and I don't know why this is.

The code is:

```
../../SPTK-3.11/bin/pitch/pitch -a 0 -s 16.0 -p 80 -t0 0.0 -L 40 -H 150 -o 1 ../wav/*.wav > f0
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot open file ../wav/arctic_a0254.wav!
```

There are around 500 wav files in the folder, so I don't know why it doesn't list the first here if there is a problem with the path or the file

I have already tried doing `ls ../wav` which shows all the files as being in that directory, and did `open ../wav/arctic_a0254.wav` which also worked, so I don't know why there is an error here.

EDIT: I tried removing the wav file from the folder, and got the same error with the proceeding wav file (arctic_a0255.wav), so I don't think it is to do with the individual wav file.

EDIT2: The script lists the error as occurring when there is an error seeking the beginning of the audio container, but I'm not sure what this means

EDIT3: Solved! The issue was the file not being a float, so I converted the wav in audacity and the script worked as normal

Comment: What does "ls -l ../wav/arctic_a0254.wav" say? 
Maybe it doesn't have the proper format?  Did you try "file ../wav/arctic_a0254.wav" ?

Comment: `file ../wav/arctic_a0254.wav` gives `RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 16000 Hz` which is the same as a random sample of others that I checked. I have already done pitch tracking using a different script and did not get an error then

Comment: Did you check file permissions to execute? `chmod a+x -R ../wav`

Comment: chmod didn't change anything, I think it has to do with how the speech data needs to be in 'float format' but at the moment it is a .wav

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the program you are executing, *pitch*, runs out of file descriptors.

I don't know whether it fails to close already used files, thus *leaking* file descriptors, or whether it really needs to keep all those files open for performing its task, which would be more difficult to fix.

You can try to *strace* it and see the exact error you get from the read() system call just before bailing out.

Do you have access to the source?

Can you run it in smaller batches?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what your asking, but I looked for the error in the original script and it listed it as a 'ReadAudioData' error, and in the manual example, the wav file is in a float format so I think I may need to change it to that

Comment: So you have WAVs with different types?  Can you try to convert it?  
What you said about it failing with the "next" file when you remove an offending one suggested me the application is leaking file descriptors. 

strace would cast light on this.

Comment: I am currently looking at how to convert a wav to a float format

Comment: I suggest you to overwrite one of those float format files with another working one.

Comment: I have 593 wav files

Comment: So this is probably not the problem. Finding out open()s failure would be useful